# Integration (Struggling on the Algebra)

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

This is the question --> [image]

---

What I have done;

$$ \int_0^{12} p(x)(x-c)dx = 0$$

$$ \int_0^{12} bx^r(12-x)(x-c)dx= 0$$

$$ b \int_0^{12} ((12+c)x^{r+1}-12cx^r - x^{r+2})dx = 0 $$

$$ \left[ {(12+c)x^{r+2}\over r+2} - {12cx^{r+1}\over r+1} - {x^{r+3}\over r+3} \right]^{12}_{0} = 0$$

$$ \left[ {(12+c)12^{r+2}\over r+2} - {12c*12^{r+1}\over r+1} - {12^{r+3}\over r+3} \right] = 0 $$

This is where I am stuck! How do i go and solve for c?

Comment: it does not help to post images instead of text -- i cannot read your image because of local settings here, but would be able to help if text was given instead of a pic...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divide both sides by $12^{r+2}$ to get
$$
\frac{12+c}{r+2} - \frac{c}{r+1} - \frac{12}{r+3} = 0
$$
which is a linear equation in $c$...